# Jquery hover only at the last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

I have following html structure:

```
<div id="123" class="test">
   <div class="testMessage">Foo</div>
   <div><div class="testDate">2010</div></div>
   <div id="127" class="test">
      <div class="testMessage">Bar</div>
      <div><div class="testDate">2011</div></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And following JS code:

```
$(".test").live({
    mouseenter:
        function()
        {
            $(this).find(".testDate").show();
        },
    mouseleave:
        function()
        {
            $(this).find(".testDate").hide();
        }
});
```

The problem is that when mouse pointer is at `#127` `.testDate` in `#123` also displayed. I think it's because hover works for parent element. How to fix it?

Thanx!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but IDs are not allowed to start with a digit. It might sovle some browser quirks.

Comment: How does this relate to java???

Comment: Give me a second and I'll knock up an example for you

Comment: That is the expected behavior, you are binding the same event handlers to two nested elements. What is your desired effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".test").live({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.testDate:first', this).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.testDate:first', this).hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is because you have one element '.test' inside another '.test'. If you split them, your code will work. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/WYuFm/) is working example.

Comment: Yes i think there is a missing closing off div tag thats required.

Comment: Not sure its missing... Div#123 wraps div#127. Markup is all fine, I suppose.

Comment: Yes the markup he has provided is fine but sometimes you miss these little things and it maybe that each .test is a section within parent.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Maybe author wants markup be exactly as in question, but for me it doesn't make sense. Anyway, we can change the js-code a little to fit markup requirements. ;-)

Comment: This is not mistake. I have .test > .test structure.

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LtMPp/1/) sample. Problem in your code is that you're listening event for `test` class. Event firing for each element, so for your markup it will fire twice: one for the parent `test` and another for child `test`.